# iphone custom photo album view in inside of the appication(thumbnail)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, photo

is it possible to implement the photolibrary view to the custom thumbnail view as the default one is the grid list..(ie.,for example listing it in a uitableview)can u please help me out..i was strucked with this one from past one week....

Answer (score 1):

Read about ALAssetsLibrary
here is my code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    void (^assetEnumerator)(struct ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            if(result != NULL) {
                //Add result to your array for UITableView
            }
        };

        void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
            if(group != nil) {
                [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
            }
        };

        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes: ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
                               usingBlock: assetGroupEnumerator
                             failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                                                NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
                                            }];

}
```